# How do I implement dio http cache alongside my interceptor

Tags: flutter, dio

Here is my interceptor setup :

```
class AppInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  Dio previous;
  AppInterceptor() {}

  AppInterceptor.firebaseIDToken() {
    this.dio.interceptors.add(
          InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (options, handler) async {
            var token = await getAuthorizationToken();
            options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer $token';
            dio.unlock();
            handler.next(options);
          }, onResponse: (response, handler) {
           
            return handler.next(response);
          
          }, onError: (DioError e, handler) {
            
            return handler.next(e);
            
          }
              
              ),
        );
  }

...

}
```

And here is how I make http request:

```
Response response;
if (user != null) {
     response = await AppInterceptor.tokenAuthorization()
      .dio.get(Global.apiurl + 'jobs/detail/$pageid? 
 coordinates=$coordinates');
} else {
 response = await AppInterceptor.apikey().dio.get(Global.apiurl + 
 'jobs/detail/$pageid?coordinates=$coordinates');
      }
return Job.fromJson(response.data);
```

Now what I want to do is add the dio HTTP cache interceptor
https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache

```
dio.interceptors.add(DioCacheManager(CacheConfig(baseUrl: "http://www.google.com")).interceptor);
```

google.com here should be my Global.apiurl

My question is, how do I go about adding this to my above implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this problem earlier and actually found my way through Dio's doc. I learned that `handler` actually have method other than `next` which is `resolve`.

To resolve onError with custom Response (in this case, something from your cache), you should resolve the `handler` instead of passing it through `next`.

I made the interceptor as it's own class and specifically return cached response only on Connection Timeout & Other Error.

```js
class CacheInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final _cache = <Uri, Response>{};

  @override
  onRequest(options, handler) => handler.next(options);

  @override
  onResponse(response, handler) {
    // Cache the response with uri as key
    _cache[response.requestOptions.uri] = response;

    handler.resolve(response);
  }

  @override
  onError(DioError err, handler) {
    var isTimeout = err.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout;
    var isOtherError = err.type == DioErrorType.other;

    if (isTimeout || isOtherError) {
      // Read cached response if available by uri as key
      var cachedResponse = _cache[err.requestOptions.uri];

      if (cachedResponse != null) {
        // Resolve with cached response
        return handler.resolve(cachedResponse);
      }
    }

    return handler.next(err);
  }
}
```

And then, add the `CacheInterceptor` above to the Dio instance

```js
...


dio.interceptors
  ..add(CacheInterceptor())
  ..add(LogInterceptor());


...
```